# writing view part for Play-java applications

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

i created a Play-java application using template.
if i open the sample application created, there is folder called /views under /app folder. so, each file in /views is a HTML file with Scla code like main.scala.html and index.scala.html

questions is:
i want to write a login page with no knowledge of scala language. is it mandatory to learn scala to write view in Play-java application? cant i use JSP to views? please help in understanding how to write views.

note: i have used MVC frameworks like struts, spring, etc. there we used JSP to write views.

Comment: no. this is not duplicate of the link said. my actual a question is, i want to write a login page with no knowledge of scala language. is it mandatory to learn scala to write view in Play-java application?

Comment: If you want to pass information from your contollers to your view the yes you have to learn a little bit of scala.
AFAIK there is no support fo a different MVC framework. You can however use frameworks like AngluarJS etc. within your view (which is HTML after all) and transmit data via e.g. REST API calls.

Comment: you dont have to learn scala. the "scala-part" in the play twirl templates is more like a simple expression language. there are just some basics like "@if" or "@for". Or for form Fields you can use the input helper files. @helper.inputText. so there is no direct need for you to learn scala.